# Correct way to center page?

Tags: html, css

I'm re-writing my web pages to learn more about HTML5. Currently I'm using a wrapper div for the page contents, with:

```
#pageContainer { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Is this still the correct/best way of centering a page?

Thanks!

Comment: @Adel your link is irrelevant with the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still the preferred way.

HTML5 and CSS3 may not be as revolutionary as you think, basic layouting techniques are still the same, with a few more tricks, and less worry about old browsers as they disappear.

Answer (score -3):

Another common method would be:

```
#container{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left: -500px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: not necessarily see this http://jsbin.com/iyomiv/1/edit a far better method for centering absolute divs

Comment: Well, I've seen this used quite a lot, but thanks for sharing a better way.